# How to execute a SQL Server Job on AppHarbor SQL database?

Tags: database, jobs, appharbor

How to execute a SQL Server Job on AppHarbor database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to my earlier posted query. SQL server jobs are executed on AppHarbor as Background worker. The process is simple. 1. Create a windows job (any project that outputs an exe). 2. Integrate job with Quartz for scheduling 3. Upload to AppHarbor. 4. If you're already using a web or background worker, you may need to get extra subscription for a background worker.

The background worker automatically picks up the exe and executes it.

Regards, 
Chandana