# Querying index statistics in AppHarbor

Tags: sql-server, indexing, appharbor

I'd like to monitor the statistics of my indexes on my sql server instance of my app harbor website. But running my query says I don't have permission to access that object. Is there other ways to query the dm_* tables/views to get these statistics so I know whether to add more indexes, rebuild/reorg my current ones, etc?

Comment: The required permissions for these DMVs are all documented on books online. Maybe you could request e.g. `VIEW DATABASE STATE`.

Comment: well to query the statistics you have to have enough permissions weather executing query or by executing system proc/fun. that's why such task are executed as SQL jobs with enough permissions and results are sent to concerned people. in your case Are you saying that by monitoring Index statistics live you will be able to take immediate decision about what to add and what to Drop? because Statistics/fragmentation etc.. information trigger any action after certain benchmark crossed. and that doesn't happen everyday or multiple times of day. not sure why some one would want to monitor it live?

Comment: @AnupShah I'd just like to check them once a week to see how they are performing. Since I can't schedule a SQL Server Agent job in AppHarbor, I'd have to do this manually (once a week or so).

Comment: i am not familiar with AppHarbor but is there way to schedule execution of one or more procedures? if yes then you can create a sql procs that runs with "Execute AS SELF" option and spit out the result using send_mail or something. also I found this on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984911/how-to-execute-a-sql-server-job-on-appharbor-sql-database

Comment: Interesting (the link). That sounds like the exe is only executed once...but I'll definitely look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yet to answer your question:

In order to view the statistics object, the user must own the table or the user must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.

[DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS @ BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

EDIT1:

As Martin pointed out if it is about querying information from Catalog then depending on SQL SERVER version you need to grant some permission to user who wants to access this information. check the BOL guideline for that:

[Metadata Visibility Configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I think they mean statistics about the indexes (e.g. `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`) not statistics belonging to the indexes.